# PHP Preg_match pattern to remove time from subtitle srt file

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I need a preg_match expression to remove all the timings from a .srt subtitle file (imported as a string) but I could never quite get my head round regex patterns. So for example it would change:

```
5
00:05:50,141 --> 00:05:54,771
This is what was said
```

to

```
This is what was said
```

Comment: Have you got a few more examples so we can actually see how they vary please.

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/QY9QXG/1

Comment: @Doug they really don't. The first digit is the count of subtitle, new line,  then the start time and end time. Then new line and the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where you got stuck it's only \d+ and colon/comma really.

```
$re = '/\d+.\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+\s-->\s\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+./s';
//$re = '\d+.[0-9:,]+\s-->\s[\d+:,]+./s'; //slightly compacter version of the regex
$str = '5
00:05:50,141 --> 00:05:54,771
This is what was said';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

Working demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/QY9QXG/1).
With the little compacter pattern it looks like: https://regex101.com/r/QY9QXG/2

---

And just for the fun and challenge. Here is a non regex answer. https://3v4l.org/r7hbO

```
$str = "1
00:05:50,141 --> 00:05:54,771
This is what was said1

2
00:05:50,141 --> 00:05:54,771
This is what was said2

3
00:05:50,141 --> 00:05:54,771
This is what was said3

4
00:05:50,141 --> 00:05:54,771
This is what was said4
LLLL

5
00:05:50,141 --> 00:05:54,771
This is what was said5";


$count = explode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, $str);

foreach($count as &$line){
    $line =  implode(PHP_EOL, array_slice(explode(PHP_EOL, $line), 2));
}

echo implode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, $count);
```

The non regex will first split on double new lines which means each new subtitle group is a new item in the array.
Then loop though them and explode again on new line.
First two lines are not wanted, array slice them away.
If the subtitle is more than one line I need to merge them. Do that with implode on new line.

Then as the last step rebuild the string again with implode on double new line.

> As Casimir wrote in comments below I have used PHP_EOL as new line and that works in the example.
>   But when used on a real srt file the new line may be different.
>   If the code does not work as expected try replacing PHP_EOL with some other new line.

Comment: Thanks Aravindh. Forgot the link.

Comment: Anyone who can comment on the downvote? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Well it wasn't me that down voted it. I'll try it out.

Comment: Works absolutely perfect! Amazing work. And yes I got stuck right from the beginning when I tried to use regex which I don't now how to use.

Comment: @Hasen thanks. I just noticed I made a mistake in the compact regex. A + was missing.

Comment: Be careful with `PHP_EOL`. `PHP_EOL` is the default newline *for php*, but the newline in the file can be different.

Comment: @Casimir that is true. If the non regex is used by anyone they should try out what type of new line is used. Good point! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since a srt file has always the same format, you can skip the two first lines for each block of lines and return the result once the empty line is reached. To do that and to avoid to load the whole file in memory, you can read the file by line and use a generator:

```
function getSubtitleLine($handle) {
    $flag = 0;
    $subtitle = '';
    while ( false !== $line = stream_get_line($handle, 1024, "\n") ) {
        $line = rtrim($line);
        if ( empty($line) ) {
            yield $subtitle;
            $subtitle = '';
            $flag = 0;
        } elseif ( $flag == 2 ) {
            $subtitle .= empty($subtitle) ? $line : "\n$line";
        } else {
           $flag++;
        }
    }

    if ( !empty($subtitle) )
        yield $subtitle;
}

if ( false !== $handle = fopen('./test.srt', 'r') ) {
    foreach (getSubtitleLine($handle) as $line) {
        echo $line, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So considering `This is what was said` Start with a Uppercase and can be a text with punctuation, I propose the following :

```
$re = '/.*([A-Z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9 _.,?!"\/\'$]*)/';

$str = '5
00:05:50,141 --> 00:05:54,771
This is what was said.';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Keep in mind it's subtitle file. As in the subtitle you see on films and TV shows. So more than A-z is needed it my opinion.

Comment: May work. But if you want to use Preg_match on srt files. My best guess it to use the specification of the file type to your advantage. What I mean is that the filetype MUST have and empty line between the count of the subtitle and the previous subtitle text. So looking at the example above the "5" there is a blank line, and above the blank line there is "subtitle count 4's text". So anything between time and the blank line (lazy) will be the text.  (should be at least)

Comment: Here is how a srt file should be built https://matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/srt.html

Comment: Also concider using preg_match_all. Since it's likely there is more than one subtitleline in the file.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code:

```
$str = '5
00:05:50,141 --> 00:05:54,771
This is what was said';
$reg = '/(.{0,}[0,1]{0,}\s{0,}[0-9]{0,}.{0,}[0-9]+[0-9]+:[0-9]{0,}.{0,})/';
echo(trim(preg_replace($reg, '', $str)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your .srt files come from different places and are not well formatted, you can use a library that would parse them correctly and would extract the text:

```
$srt = '
   5
   00:05:50,141 --> 00:05:54,771
   This is what was said
';
echo Subtitles::loadFromString($srt)->content('txt'); // Output: This is what was said
```

https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles